# member and defparameter

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, member

In the following Lisp REPL interaction:

```
CL-USER> (defparameter *unison* 0)
*UNISON*
CL-USER> (member *unison* '(*unison*))
NIL
```

why is nil returned?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the `*unison*` variable is bound to `0`, and the list has only a `*unison*` symbol since it's quoted.  Try this in comparison:

```
(member *unison* (list *unison*))
```

This will actually evaluate the second `*unison*` which returns `0`, resulting in a `(0)` list.

Comment: Or (less likely what he wants) (member '*unison* '(\*unison\*)).

Comment: (Yes, but given how quote can be confusing I avoided mentioning it too -- talking about it will require a separate answer, and I'd be surprised if there isn't such an answer around anyway...)